# Do most semanticists maintain that there is a distinction between secondary agents and tools?

Tags: semantics, lexical

I've heard some people say that there are two types of instrument:  secondary agents and tools.

A secondary agent is something that accomplishes a task when the agent wields it.  So we CAN say sentences such as "the knife cut the paper," "the boat crossed the river," and "the oven cooked the muffins."

A tool is something that helps an agent accomplish a task himself/herself.  We CAN say that we eat with a fork, but we CAN'T sensibly say "The fork ate the broccoli."  We CAN say that we planted a tree with a shovel, but we CAN'T sensibly say that "the shovel planted the trees".

How hard and fast is this distinction?  Have counterexamples ruled it out in the literature, is it still an open question, or is it considered established semantics?

Comment: The distinction between the Secondary Agent and the Intermediary (an independent Agent allowing the main Agent to succeed in some action) would seem to become more blurred, although there is still a difference in volitionality.

Comment: _Cross_ isn’t really a very good example. We can also say that a fork or a shovel crossed the river if the current happened to bring it from one side to the other – _cross_ can be non-volitional. Perhaps ‘the ferry manoeuvred the narrow waters’?

Comment: I think @JanusBahsJacquet's comment goes for all the examples- *I didn't put my knife away properly and it's cut through my bag*; *the bodies had lain undiscovered in the outback for 4 weeks and had been cooked by the sun*.  Is *the ferry manoeuvred the narrow waters* a case of using *the ferry* to stand for the captain / crew? If so I guess it would be the primary A. Also, it would be unfortunate if a knife turned out not to be a tool, and *the shovel dug deeper and deeper until it struck the chest* is OK for me - maybe the issue with *planted* is that the shovel is not the only tool required

Comment: William Frawley (Frawley 1992) calls them differently, **author** (or **effector**) and **instrument** - see pp. 205-210 for a more detailed discussion with examples and references.  https://www.routledge.com/Linguistic-Semantics/Frawley/p/book/9780805810752

Comment: He mentions DeLancey 1984, which can be found on Academia https://www.academia.edu/3985847/Notes_on_agentivity_and_causation or on the journal platform https://www.jbe-platform.com/content/journals/10.1075/sl.8.2.05del

Comment: I feel like the unacceptability of "The fork ate the broccoli" is not just about a fork being a tool that assists an agent, but also about the subject of "eat" having other semantic roles than just "agent". A prototypical event of "eating" affects the state of the subject as well as the object; but the state of a fork does not change in the expected way when it is merely used for eating. In contrast, with "the boat crossed the river", the boat does undergo the change in position that is usually associated with the subject of the verb "cross".